# Can I reference a Smartsheet column by name instead of index?

Tags: smartsheet-api

I have  a smartsheet integration where I'm obtaining data from another program via a web service and writing into a sheet.  The relevant code to populate the sheet is here:

```
         Cell[] cellsA = new Cell[] 
         { 
         new Cell.AddCellBuilder(sheet.Columns[0].Id, projectData[i][0].Trim()).Build()                   //Project ID
         ,new Cell.AddCellBuilder(sheet.Columns[1].Id, projectData[i][1].Trim()).Build()                  //Customer
         ,new Cell.AddCellBuilder(sheet.Columns[2].Id, projectData[i][2].Trim()).Build()                  //Description
         ,new Cell.AddCellBuilder(sheet.Columns[3].Id, projectData[i][3].Trim()).Build()                  //Status
         ,new Cell.AddCellBuilder(sheet.Columns[4].Id, startDate).SetStrict(false).Build()                //StartDate
         ,new Cell.AddCellBuilder(sheet.Columns[5].Id, endDate).SetStrict(false).Build()                  //EndDate
         ,new Cell.AddCellBuilder(sheet.Columns[6].Id, projectData[i][6].Trim()).Build()                  //Project Manager
         };
         // Specify contents of first row.
         Row rowA = new Row.AddRowBuilder(null, true, null, null, null).SetCells(cellsA).Build();
```

My question is, instead of using

```
sheet.Columns[0].Id
```

Is it possible to use a column name to identify a specific column instead of the index?  The reason being if a user moves or rearranges  columns, this will result in errors (date formats, etc.).

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot programmatically reference a column by name (even if you could, you probably wouldn’t want to — because name is subject to change, just like position is), but you can programmatically reference a column by ID (which will never change, even if the column is moved or renamed).

Comment: Thanks!  Once I determine those column IDs - can I assume that they are set in stone for that sheet going forward?

Comment: Yes, a column’s ID should never change.